# Sending data along with a redirect in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a simple C (of CRUD) function, and I'd like to send a message (error or success) along with my redirect from the "insert" function I have written up. Is there a way to adhere a POST field with a redirect?

In pseudo code I have:

```
function view_all{
    //set up some initial variables
    $this->load->view(viewing_page, $data)
}

function insert{
    if ($this->db->insert(my_table, $_POST)){
        $message = "All's well";
    }
    else {
        $message = "whoops!";
    }
    redirect(view_all);
}
```

So the viewing_page ideally would have something like

```
if (isset($message)){
    echo $message
}
```

So on the first time through, I don't see any message, and when/if there's an insert, it pops up the same page with the message. Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe `redirect` uses `header()`. If so, I don't believe you can send data along with a location header. You could accomplish the same thing using session vars or (not as good) appending a query string to the location URL.

For an 'accepted' way to do this in CodeIgniter look a little more than halfway down the [session class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) documentation page.

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for informational or status messages (for example: "record 2 deleted").

This (now deleted - here's an [archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20100815075820/http://blog.agilephp.com/2008/06/03/flash-messages/)) [post on flash messages](http://blog.agilephp.com/2008/06/03/flash-messages/) covers both the query string and the session var method.

**Update**: To summarize the now deleted post, it showed both urlencoding a message and appending as a query string (example from post):

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?message='.urlencode($message));
```

And setting a 'flash' variable using two frameworks (example from post):

```
//Zend Framework
$flashMessenger = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger;
$flashMessenger->setNamespace('actionErrors');
$flashMessenger->addMessage($message);

//CakePHP
$this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
$this->redirect('/news/index');
```

Of course you can do roughly the same thing using `$_SESSION` directly (my example):

```
//first request
$_SESSION['flash'] = 'This is a simple flash message.';
//next request
$flash = $_SESSION['flash'];
unset($_SESSION['flash']); //flash is one time only
```

Comment: Session is the only way to accomplish this unless you use query strings which get messy with the URI routing that CI has. +1 for this answer.

Comment: Like Jessedc said, sessions are the only way. I use flash data for this type of application. I typically, set the flash data, the redirect. It also helps prevent users from resubmitting data.

Comment: @TimLytle the post link you mentioned is not working. What was it about?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar Updated with some examples taken from the cached page.

Answer (score 27):

You can use Flashdata in the CI [Session Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html). This is what's said in the document:

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be
>   available for the next server request, and are then automatically
>   cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for
>   informational or status messages (for example: "record 2 deleted").

Note: Flash variables are prefaced with "flash_" so avoid this prefix in your own session names.

To add flashdata:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

You can also pass an array to `set_flashdata()`, in the same manner as `set_userdata()`.

To read a flashdata variable:

```
$this->session->flashdata('item');
```

If you find that you need to preserve a flashdata variable through an additional request, you can do so using the `keep_flashdata()` function.

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that CodeIgniter destroys the current session on logout. This makes it more difficult to pass along a message along the lines of "you have logged in/out" as you cannot use flash or session storage. If you need to pass a message when transitioning between logged in and out states, I suggest using [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php). Other options (mentioned above) are [using URL query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838058/enable-query-strings-in-code-igniter) and [setting cookies](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html).