# Enable Query Strings in Code Igniter

Tags: url, codeigniter, query-string

I am trying to implement Twitter's OAuth into my Code Igniter web application at which the callback URL is `/auth/` so once you have authenticated with Twitter you are taken to `/auth/?oauth_token=SOME-TOKEN`.

I want to keep the nice clean URL's the framework provides using the `/controller/method/` style of URL but I want to enable query strings as well, there will only ever be one name of the data `oauth_token` so it's ok if it has to be hard coded.

Any ideas?
I have tried tons of the things people are saying to do, but none work :(
PS: I'm using the .htaccess method of URL rewriting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this.

Most People, and Elliot Haughin's Twitter Lib, extend the `CI_Input` library with a `MY_Input` library that sets `allow_query_strings` to `true`

You will also need to add `?` to the allowed characters in `config/config.php` and set $config['url_protocal'] to `PATH_INFO`

see here: [Enable GET in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043070/enabling-get-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

[Codeigniter Reactor](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor) lets you access $_GET directly or via $this->input->get(). You don't need to use MY_Input or even change your config.php. This method leaves the query string in the URL, however.

Answer (score 0):

I used a hacked index.php to recognise users coming back from Twitter, check for valid and safe values, then re-direct it to to a CodeIgniter friendly URL.

It may not be to everyones taste but I preferred it over allowing query strings throughout the entire application instead of just one particular circumstance.

Comment: If you going to go that route, why not just have a separate PHP file that does a query string to URI segment conversion? I think that would be better than hacking up CI's index.php.

Comment: Yeah I guess, I just added a one line include to the php file that determines whether to intercept or not.