# codeigniter : load second controller after execution of first controller

Tags: codeigniter

we have two controllers one is `members.php` which is registering the user another one is    `reserv.php` for reserving a ticket for busses.

I want to load second controller after completion of first controller class.

**members.php**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Members1 extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('member_model1');
    }

    public function index() {
        $table = $this->member_model1->insert_members();
        $data['members'] = $table;
        //$this->load->view('header1', $data);
        $this->load->view('reservation_view',$data);
        //$this->load->view('members');
        //$this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

**reserv.php**

```
<?php 

class reserve extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('member_model1');
    }

    function index() {
        $table = $this->member_model1->get_members();
        $data['members'] = $table;
        //$this->load->view('header1', $data);
        $this->load->view('reservation_view',$data);
        //$this->load->view('reservation_view');    
        // $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        //$this->load->view('reservation_view');
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Redirect user to the second `controller/action` URI by: `redirect(site_url('reserve'));`. but make sure you have loaded `url` helper before.

Comment: You can make redirect after registration to another controller which would work for your case imo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a controller from another controller, you can use the function [redirect()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) :

```
// In Members1 controller
redirect('/reserve/index');
```

Note that you won't be able to send data along with the redirect, such as when you load a view. To send data, you must use `$this->session->set_flashdata();` because the redirects seem to use `header()` (I advise you to have a loot at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837467/sending-data-along-with-a-redirect-in-codeigniter)).

```
// In Members1 controller
$this->session->set_flashdata('key', 'value');
redirect('/reserve/index');
```

By the way, when I look at your two classes, I wonder why you don't simply create a unique `Ticket` class with two methods like `registerUser()` and `bookTicket()` (these names are pure fancy, be free to use yours).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion..i will modify my application as your suggestion