# How to pass a message from model to controller codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to pass a message variable in some conditions to controller from model in codeigniter. But when i am doing this it is printing only "No" everytime.

Model is

```
public function add_city() {

    /* Storing form data into an array */
    $data = array(
        'city_name' => $this->input->post('city'),
        'city_overview' => $this->input->post('overview')
    );

    /* Checking if already exist in database */
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM city_tbl WHERE city_name='" . $data['city_name'] . "' ORDER BY id ASC");
    $count_row = $query->num_rows();

    if ($count_row > 0) {
        $msg = "No";
    } else {
        $this->db->insert('city_tbl', $data);
        $msg = "Yes";
    }
    return $msg;
}
```

And Controller is

```
public function addingCity() {
    $this->add_model->add_city();
    var_dump($msg);
    //redirect("/city");
}
```

Comment: My model and controller code is here
http://www.theumang.com/lm/model.html
http://www.theumang.com/lm/controller.html

Comment: r u sure u have data in table ? and the query is correct ?

Comment: Yes i am sure, there is data in the table or if not then it should print "Yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This also

```
public function add_city() {

$data = array(
    'city_name' => $this->input->post('city'),
    'city_overview' => $this->input->post('overview')
);

/* Checking if already exist in database */
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM city_tbl WHERE city_name='" .    $data['city_name'] . "' ORDER BY id ASC");
$count_row = $query->num_rows();

if ($count_row > 0) {
    $msg = "No";
} else {
    $this->db->insert('city_tbl', $data);
    $msg = "Yes";
}
return $msg;
}
```

On controller redirect message with get method -

```
public function addingCity() {
    $msg = $this->add_model->add_city();

    redirect("/city?msg=".$msg);
}
```

And finally print this message on view page

```
echo $this->input->get('msg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function add_city() {    

    $city_name = $this->input->post('city');
    $city_overview = $this->input->post('overview');

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM city_tbl WHERE city_name='$city_name' ORDER BY id ASC");
    $result = $query->result_array()
    $count = count($result);

    if(empty($count))
    { 
        $msg = "No";
        return $msg;
    } 
    else{ 

        $data = array( 
            'city_name'=>$this->input->post('city'), 
            'city_overview'=>$this->input->post('overview') );

        $this->db->insert('city_tbl', $data);
        $msg = "Yes";
        return $msg;
    }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function addingCity() {
    $msg = $this->add_model->add_city();
    echo $msg;        
}
```

**To pass data to view**

```
public function addingCity() {
    $data['msg'] = $this->add_model->add_city();

    $this->load->view("filename", $data); # ex $this->load->view("index", $data);

}
```

Comment: It is showing this error
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: msg

Filename: controllers/addstuff.php

Comment: Still error may be we have to retrieve this variable into controller

Severity: Warning

Message: var_dump() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given

Filename: controllers/addstuff.php

Comment: use `echo` instead of `vardump`

Comment: Undefined variable: msg in controller

Comment: Can we pass this variable to a particular page with redirect method ?

Comment: dont use redirect load view with data

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign value to `$msg` in your controller

```
public function addingCity() {
    $msg=$this->add_model->add_city();// assign 
    var_dump($msg);
    //redirect("/city");
}
```

Comment: You need to  assign value to `$msg` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Error is in your controller function

Try with this code

```
public function addingCity() {
    $msg = $this->add_model->add_city();
    echo $msg;die;
    //redirect("/city");
}
```

Comment: Can we pass this variable with redirect method to particular page ?

Comment: For send message to have to check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837467/sending-data-along-with-a-redirect-in-codeigniter) @KillerHacker

Comment: No you can't pass this variable with redirect()

You can use session flash message
and in view you access the flash message
@KillerHacker