# How to redirect in CodeIgniter with Parameter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table of items listed in dashboard in which there's a menu to add certain data to it. So let's say I click item 1 to add data, I'll be directed to a page with link like `item/01/add-data/`. In this page, there's a form that you need to fill in corresponding to item 1. The problem is it's fine if the input can pass the validation form, but if it can't then there's certainly an error message shown right? Here's my problem.

I make it like this in the item controller

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', validation_errors());
        redirect('item/add_item');

      }
```

And `add_item` is a function in `item` controller. So there's that. But the problem is in redirect, it'll always reload a new page and show a blank page saying 'no data' with the error message (no form is shown). How do I reload the same page form as also put the error message above it? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data along with a redirect in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837467/sending-data-along-with-a-redirect-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I don't think that's what I am looking for. My problem is, instead of reloading the same page (and form) and shows the error, it reloads a new page and displays an error there with no form. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: instead of a link - where then you have to put stuff in the url - use a form button - with the info like what item it is. would be much simpler and also easier to extend.

Comment: Do you need to do the redirect? You could change your script so that instead of redirecting, your validation just doesn't pass and the same view gets loaded again. This way you keep your data.