# Codeigniter: change URL after loading a View

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a project which deals with lots of forms. I searched and tried the search results, but none of them worked.

My code view code "uprofile.php" is as follows:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action='<?php echo base_url() . "home/addnewagency" ?>'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company" class="col-sm-3 control-label">New Agency Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newagency" name="newagency" placeholder="Plase Enter New Agency Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My Controller "home.php" code is as follows:

```
public function addnewagency() {
        $newagency = $this->input->post('newagency');
        $this->dis_model->newagency_model(strtoupper($newagency));
        $this->loadprofile();
    }
    public function loadprofile() {
        $data['inscompanyname'] = $this->dis_model->getcompany();
        $data['agentname'] = $this->dis_model->getagent();
        $data['agencyname'] = $this->dis_model->getagency();
        $data['clientname'] = $this->dis_model->getclient();
        $data['deptname'] = $this->dis_model->getdept();
        $this->load->view('uprofile', $data);
    }
```

when I submit the form, the control is passed to `addnewagency()` data gets inserted in the database and the URL is `http://localhost/dis/home/addnewagency`. After getting back to the calling function, it goes to `loadprofile()` and loads the view `uprofile`. But, the URL still remains the same. But, I want it as *http://localhost/dis/home/login* and also want to pass the data. Does anyone have any idea regarding how to achieve this?

All positive suggestion are welcomed...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Whats in the same url?

Comment: Did you try redirect("home/login"); inside the function addnewagency()

Comment: Looks like you are doing this while you are in session. You can destroy the session after putting values and Redirect to login redirect("home/login");. just an Idea if that works

Comment: you have to redirect redirect(base_url() . 'home/loadprofile');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you are calling $this->loadprofile() within addnewagency(). If you want to change URL, you need to use redirect() function of CodeIgniter.

Replace

```
$this->loadprofile()
```

with below line of code and it will work for you.

```
redirect(base_url() . 'home/loadprofile');
```

Comment: can i pass data using redirect() ?

Comment: in redirect() function you cant pass but you can set the data in session

Comment: But, there's a lot of data. Do you think, it would be feasible to store that much data is session?

Comment: You can store upto 4kb in CodeIgniter Sessions. One thing we can do it, Pass Id and fetch data from that ID on functioan load.

Comment: I don't think this is the best anwser since the OP asked to pass data as well

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change the url use redirect(base_url() . 'home/loadprofile'); in your controller addnewagency(); as suggested by others and refer this question to know whether you can send data in redirect function or not,
[Sending data along with a redirect in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837467/sending-data-along-with-a-redirect-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 2):

I found a alternative option to get this done.
You can't change URL string with `$this->load->view` function but you can redirect to target controller function using redirect method. Before you call redirect, set flash session data using `$this->session->set_flashdata` that will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared. You can read it from [official codeiginter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata) .

Example :

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->session->login_temp_data) {
            $data = $this->session->login_temp_data;
        } else {
            $data = array();
            $data['name'] = 'Guest' ;
        }
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }

    public function get_name()
    {
       $data = [];
       $data['name'] = 'John Doe';
       $this->session->set_flashdata('login_temp_data', $data);
       redirect("login");
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the best option in my opinion. And you can retrieve like so in the view
`isset($_SESSION['login_temp_data']) ? $login_temp_data = $_SESSION['login_temp_data'] : ''; `

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `redirect()` function

At the bottom of your `addnewagency()` method like so:

```
public function addnewagency() {
    $newagency = $this->input->post('newagency');
    $this->dis_model->newagency_model(strtoupper($newagency));
    redirect(base_url() . 'home/loadprofile');
}
```